# Page aligment, how do i put my page in center when browsing in mobile?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to make my webpage responsive, so i used bootstrap. but when i see the page in a mobile (iphone 6/7/8 for example), all the content is left handed. i want it in the screen center. what am i doing wrong?

the page is:

www.elquinchodehockey.club

Comment: Find the outer header div, attach this css: `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

Comment: 1. You should remove the link to your website. 2. You should give us some code that you've tried and give us a way to understand what didn't work in your code.

Answer (score 2):

w3schools is a great website for learning, try this link [HTML Responsive Web Design](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Togvq.png)